# Expression $ne takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this to query in db :

```
const hasUsedVideo = await db.SessionCard.findOne({ movie: Card.movie, unit: Card.unit, video: Card.video }, { _id: { $ne: Card._id } }, { _id: 1 } ).lean();
```

But I get this error:

> MongoError: Expression $ne takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed
> in.

I don't know how to fix this?

Comment: `const hasUsedVideo = await db.SessionCard.findOne({ movie: Card.movie, unit: Card.unit, video: Card.video, _id: { $ne: Card._id } }, { _id: 1 } ).lean();`

Comment: The first two parts should be together as they define the conditions to find the matching document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@nimrod serok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18482310/nimrod-serok) provides the right guidance in the comments, which I'll copy below for completeness. This answer is just going to outline *why* you are receiving that error.

The solution to the problem is to include the predicate on `_id` in the rest of the object that comprises the first argument for the `findOne()` operation. So instead of:

```
const hasUsedVideo = await db.SessionCard.findOne(
  { movie: Card.movie, unit: Card.unit, video: Card.video }, 
  { _id: { $ne: Card._id } }, 
  { _id: 1 } 
).lean();
```

It should be:

```
const hasUsedVideo = await db.SessionCard.findOne(
  { movie: Card.movie, unit: Card.unit, video: Card.video,  _id: { $ne: Card._id } }, 
  { _id: 1 } 
).lean();
```

As currently written in the question, the separate second argument (of `{ _id: { $ne: Card._id } }`) is being parsed as the *projection* argument (instead of the intended projection of `{ _id: 1 }`. The [projection argument](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#std-label-find-projection) accepts aggregation expressions and syntax as of version `4.4`. This is relevant to the error that you were receiving because there are two different `$ne` operators in MongoDB:

- One is the standard [query operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) which has the syntax of `{ field: { $ne: value } }`.
- The other is [an aggregation expression](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ne/) with a syntax of `{ $ne: [ <expression1>, <expression2> ] }`.

This is why your usage of `_id: { $ne: Card._id }` was triggering the error about `$ne` requiring 2 arguments, because the aggregation variant of the operation does require that.

Mongoplayground will complain about the syntax in the question stating that [a maximum of 2 arguments are expected for `find()`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Su0lGZB6ith) (in the shell implementation). By contrast, the syntax provided by @nimrod serok [executes successfully](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EYURB5qeSNv).